# hook_node_validate called on delete?

Tags: 7, hooks, forms

Why is my [`hook_node_validate`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7) implementation being called when I try to delete a node through the node editing form (by clicking the delete button at the bottom of form)?  Validation fires and then my node doesn't get deleted which is not what I want.

I can delete without any problems when clicking on delete link at `admin/content` but not whenclicking delete button on node edit form since validation fires and fails.  What could be the reason for validation firing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nmc is right, validate functions are called for delete button as well, see http://drupal.org/node/216064 for more details

Comment: And check out efflugentsia's answer on that thread to see that you can just set the new D7 FAPI element '#limit_validation_errors' to a blank array() to remove all validation an allow deletion. http://drupal.org/node/216064#comment-2658108

Answer (score 3):

You could check the Triggering element in the Form State for the button that triggers the Form Submission.

```
function MYMODULE_node_validate($node , $form_state , $form) {
  if ($form_state['triggering_element']['#value'] != 'Delete') {
    //Include the validations here
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would work for a site that has been translated, but fine for English.

Answer (score 0):

It's not invoked when deleting a node, basing on the code for [node_delete_multiple()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_delete_multiple/7); the only functions called from that function that involve hooks are the following ones:

```
    node_invoke($node, 'delete');
    module_invoke_all('node_delete', $node);
    module_invoke_all('entity_delete', $node, 'node');
    field_attach_delete('node', $node);
```

The function is called from [node_delete()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_delete/7).

Looking at the code for [node_delete_confirm_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.pages.inc/function/node_delete_confirm_submit/7), the form submission hander executed when a node is being deleted from the node edit form through the "Delete" button, I notice the following code:

```
$node = node_load($form_state['values']['nid']);
node_delete($form_state['values']['nid']);
```

That would cause the implementations of [hook_node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7) to be invoked, but as far as I can see, it would not cause [hook_node_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7) (which is invoked from [node_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_validate/7)) to be invoked.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, please see edited question. I don't know why my validation is firing when it's **not** supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

For fix that, you can do this:

```
function [mymodule]_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // For articles for example:
  if ($form_id == 'article_node_form') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'myfunction_for_validate_article';
  }
} 

function myfunction_for_validate_article($form, &$form_state) {
  // This only will be call on insert and update.
}
```

Source: http://befused.com/drupal/form-validation

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 you can suppress validation on all node edit Delete buttons with this code in a custom module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 * 
 * Suppress validation for Delete button.
 */
function MYMODULE_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['actions']['delete']['#limit_validation_errors'] = [];
}
```